# Node oracledb not detecting if server is shutdown

Tags: node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

```
oracledb.getConnection({
      user          : "",
      password      : "",
      connectString : ""
      },
      function(err, connection) {
      if (err) {
          console.log("Error while trying to connect to DB ", err.message);
          callback(err.message);
      } else {
          //My Logic
      }
      });
```

I am connecting to remote oracledb using the above (pseudo)code. I work in windows environment. Connection string has the URL to connect to the remote DB. Now, if my username/password is incorrect/null, I am able to see that error. But, if the server is switched off, it is not coming into if section handling the error. How to catch the server shutdown error ?

Any leads will be helpful. TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably waiting for a TCP timeout.  You can play with your OS network configuration, and/or configure the Oracle Net layer (which is what handles communication between applications and the database).

Create a file `$TNS_ADMIN/sqlnet.ora` (don't forget to set `TNS_ADMIN` so it is read!) Then you can configure [`SQLNET.OUTBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/NETRF/parameters-for-the-sqlnet-ora-file.htm#NETRF427).

Depending on your application availability requirements you can also configure various other options like [`SQLNET.RECV_TIMEOUT`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/NETRF/parameters-for-the-sqlnet-ora-file.htm#NETRF227) and [`SQLNET.SEND_TIMEOUT`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/NETRF/parameters-for-the-sqlnet-ora-file.htm#NETRF228). There might be other options that are of interest to you. Finally you may want to create a `tnsnames.ora` file to configure the DB service setting (['`ENABLE=BROKEN`'](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/NETRF/local-naming-parameters-in-tnsnames-ora-file.htm#NETRF431)).

The [19c Easy Connect Plus](https://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=dblatest&id=GUID-8C85D289-6AF3-41BC-848B-BF39D32648BA) syntax is useful for setting some of these options, for example to send keepalive probes every 5 minutes to detect if the connection is still valid you can use a connect string like 'mydbhost.example.com/myservicename?expire_time=5' so you don't need to use tnsnames.ora and sqlnet.ora files for some common settings.

Comment: Thanks Chris for your continued support on node-oracledb.

Comment: Thank you.  I've added some notes on this to the node-oracledb manual: https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/dev-2.0/doc/api.md#connectionha